# The package is accessible from more than one module (Error fix for using SAX in Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, sax

There are a lot of questions out there with this problem but i haven't found a solution for using SAX with this problem, so I found a simple workaround for me I wanted to share as a own answer.

In my case I imported this class and got the famous error you will know about if you have it to. :D

```
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
```

[image]

I tried the solutions from the other questions with similar titels, but without a working solution.

Look at the answers to see what I did. If you have a better solution please send other answers to this question :)

Answer (score 0):

**To understand the problem:**
This error will happen if Java can't unique identify your class.

I know that this is a problem with newer Java versions and modules so I tried to find out if I have a module with this class, because SAX is included in the JRE.

All you need to do is to remove the java.xml Module, what you can do in Eclipse if you open the Build Path and go to Module Dependencies.

Just click to the remove button when you selected it, to remove the module.

That's it, simple right? The only problem is when you need other Classes that require this module, than you need to find a better solution.

[image]